# Identifying CRS

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a co-ordinate for a location (EDAR06) in the South of the Sudan. The scientific paper states it as:
N  17  40  342   E  034  44  477

[image]

I also have a drawing of the area that shows the location of the above reference point.
But the 2 do not agree.[image]

Has the author mis-printed the co-ordinates?

I do not recognise the format N xx xx xxx E yyy yy yyy

Or is it my ignorance and confusion of CRS?

Comment: One way to bruteforce this would be to create a layer with these coordinates and just change the crs of the layer. Maybe there was a typo or its a now less common geographic crs.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it looks OK for WGS84, and the format is in D°M.MM'

```
17° 40.342' N, 34° 44.477' E
```

[image]

Comment: That was my assumption, but the co-ordinates do not match up with the drawing/map; up to 20km out. I will work on the assumption that the drawing is quite a way from 'to scale'.